# binning-bucketing numerical values in .net

Tags: c#, .net, f#, histogram, bucket

Is there a .net framework function to bin-bucket numerical values, for example for the sake of preparing data for an histogram chart?
I find it odd I might have to code one up myself.
Probably I am not browsing around with the right keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a function that will automatically prepare data for a histogram (including the calculation of the right number of buckets), but you can quite easily create histograms using `Seq.countBy`.

For example, given a sequence of numbers `nums` between -1 and 1, you can write something like:

```ml
nums
|> Seq.countBy (fun v -> round(v*10.0))
```

This will create buckets for numbers in intervals ... (-0.1, 0.0), (0.0, 0.1), (0.1, 0.2), ... etc. and it will return the count of numbers in each bucket. If you pipe the result to the `Chart.Bar` function from F# Charting, then you'll get a reasonably nice histogram.

Comment: Very nice candidate for MoreLinq in C#.